# youtube iframe playlist with listType flash seems to be broken

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, playlist

It looks like the flash player from youtube is broken when using a playlist iframe option.
The html5 player is working well

example

http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=search&list=jazz

Error undefined video rendering

I know Jeff is watching this site so Jeff have a look

example test site http://www.cfcms.nl/youtube-responsive/

UPDATE: This issue has been solved by the youtube engineers

Comment: Let's follow up at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4122

Comment: This issue has been solved by the youtube engineers

Comment: Hai Jeff, this issue has been back now for a week